Extract common method for Pothos (Prisma)
I'm using pothos and prisma, have some similar crud operations and want to create some generic method for it. But I'm stuck with types.
For example - I have method to querying list.
builder.queryField('groups', (t) =>
  t.prismaField({
    type: ['Group'],
    args: {
      ...createSorterAndFilterArgs(t.arg)
    },
    resolve: async (query, _parent, _args, _ctx, _info) => {
      const { sorter, filter } = _args
      return await prisma.group.findMany({
        ...query,
        orderBy: applySorting(sorter),
        where: {
          name: !!filter?.searchString
            ? { contains: filter.searchString, mode: 'insensitive' }
            : undefined
        }
      })
    }
  })
)

When I'm trying to pass parameter for "type" - there is a trouble with type for "query" param in "resolve" method.
type Options = {
  queryName: string

  type: [keyof PrismaTypes]
}

const common = ({ queryName, type }: Options) => {
  builder.queryField(queryName, (t) =>
    t.prismaField({
      type: type,
      args: {
        ...createSorterAndFilterArgs(t.arg)
      },
      resolve: async (query, _parent, _args, _ctx, _info) => {
        const { sorter, filter } = _args
        return await prisma.group.findMany({
          ...query,
          orderBy: applySorting(sorter),
          where: {
            name: !!filter?.searchString
              ? { contains: filter.searchString, mode: 'insensitive' }
              : undefined
          }
        })
      }
    })
  )
}

common({ queryName: 'groups', type: ['Group'] })

Screenshot with error
I tried different types to pass as parameter, but cannot resolve this problem.

Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
